# SQL query returning wrong values

Tags: mysql, sql

i am working on filter search for that i can to make up a query but its AND part  is not returning me the correct value, its returning right results for gpa but its not giving correct result for degree check as it return all record does not apply "BSCS" filter  here is the query code :

```
SELECT *
FROM education
WHERE gpa >= 2.10
OR gpa =0
AND degree = 'BSCS'
OR degree = NULL
```

Comment: @Juhana didnt get your point ?

Comment: Your query asks for either gpa>=2.10 or zero gpa for BSCS degrees or no degree at all. So as long as gpa >= 2.10 you query does not care about the degree.

Comment: how can i modify my query it user does not apply gpa or degree filter and sql should return all records?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you need to add some parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM education
WHERE (gpa >= 2.10 OR gpa =0)
AND (degree = 'BSCS' OR degree is NULL)
```

If you want to expand on the `WHERE` clause, then you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM education
WHERE 
(
  (gpa >= 2.10 OR gpa =0)
  AND (degree = 'BSCS' OR degree is NULL)
)
OR
(
  (gpa is null or gpa ='')
  or (degree is null or degree = '')
)
```

Comment: how can i modify my query it user does not apply gpa or degree filter and sql should return all records?

Comment: @JunaidAkhtar You can expand your `WHERE` clause depending on what you want to return, see my edit for a sample

Comment: It doesnt worked your last one if i put empty values it should return entire record

Comment: @JunaidAkhtar can you edit your OP with some sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: my query is basically if user does not want to enter any filter query must return all records..

Comment: @JunaidAkhtar My suggestion would be to post a new question with everything that you need the query to do.  You have now requested the query to do something different that your original post.

Comment: i have posted please check new one

Comment: How to convert if expression into sql query  thats my new title please check it

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

Always put parentheses when using And/OR condition to avoid confusion.
Also the best way to check if a field is null is `WHERE myField IS NULL`

```
SELECT *
FROM education
WHERE (gpa >= 2.10 OR gpa =0 )
AND (degree = 'BSCS' OR degree is NULL)
```

Comment: @Junaid Akhtar Kindly accept/vote if you are happy with solution. My answer is not duplication but someone has updated the code.... ha ha